# How to specify disabledTextColor when migrating from FlatButton to TextButton

Tags: flutter

Consider the following code that specifies `disabledTextColor` for a `FlatButton`:

```dart
FlatButton.icon(
  icon: const Icon(Icons.check_box),
  label: const Text('Foo'),
  disabledTextColor: Colors.black,
  onPressed: null,
),
```

How can I translate the `disabledTextColor` to the equivalent for `TextButton`?

I figure I need to override `style`, but I can't seem to get [`TextButton.styleFrom`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton/styleFrom.html) to work, and `Theme.of(context).textButtonTheme.style` is *null*.

Comment: Opened a Flutter issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67330

Answer (score 10):

The following are equivalent:

```dart
            FlatButton.icon(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.check_box),
              label: const Text('FlatButton'),
              disabledTextColor: Colors.black,
              onPressed: null,
            ),
            TextButton.icon(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.check_box),
              label: const Text('TextButton'),
              style: ButtonStyle(
                foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black),
              ),
              onPressed: null,
            ),
```

In this case, since `onPressed` is `null`, the button will *always* be *disabled*, so the `foregroundColor` can simply be black in *all* cases.  However, if you have a different scenario, the `style` can do something like:

```dart
style: ButtonStyle(
    foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
      (Set<MaterialState> states) => states.contains(MaterialState.disabled) ? Colors.black : null,
    ),
  ),
```

[Migrating to the New Material Buttons and their Themes - Migrating buttons with custom disabled colors](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yohSuYrvyya5V1hB6j9pJskavCdVq9sVeTqSoEPsWH0/edit#heading=h.dvt3r3o28kax) provides more details.

Answer (score 0):

Define `onPressed` before `ButtonStyle`:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final onPressed = something == true ? (){...} : null;  

    final flatButtonStyle = TextButton.styleFrom(
        foregroundColor: onPressed == null ? Colors.grey : Colors.white
    ...

return TextButton(
      onPressed: onPressed,
      style: flatButtonStyle,

       ...
```

Comment: Hey, why downvoted? Is it because the code does not compile? )))